# Get an [String] link from a json file

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, request

Here is my structure for the json file

```
    struct DataRespons: Codable {
        
        let data: [String]
        let status: String
    }
```

JSON file url

```
    {
        "status": "success",
        "data": [
            "f7c75c1f-10ab-4298-9dc9-e80b7bd07dfd",
            "6f5f6eeb-191d-4ad9-b5ef-6f61fd5fcefc",
            "8008800880088008",
            "64a3f5d0-37c7-4c30-8d0f-3b67fb5c8fde"
        ]
    }
```

This is my class for JSON requests and decoding
I use these functions to get an array of links

I hope I wrote correctly what I want to receive, and if there are any questions, please contact me

```
    @MainActor
    class NetworkModel: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var listId: [String] = []
        var statusList = ""
        var statusUser = ""
        @Published var userData = UserRespons(status: "??", data: UserData(id: "???", firstName: "???", lastName: "??", age: 4, gender: "???", country: "???"))
                
        func getList() {
            guard let url = URL(string: "some URL") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.addValue("bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Requst error",error)
                    return
                }
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
                if response.statusCode == 200 {
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        do {
                            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataRespons.self, from: data)
                            self.listId = decoded.data
                            self.statusList = decoded.status
                        } catch let error{
                            print("Error decode",error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
```

I can't through index [String] to get each element

Comment: What is your question, what is the issue with your code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I cant get data for self List id

Comment: Is there any error in debugger screen?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik no

Comment: if you add `print(self.listId)` just after `self.listId = decoded.data`, show us what you get? Also add `print("\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` just before `let decoded = ...` and show us what you get.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code so I would start to add print statements or debug the code to see what gets executed. Besides what is suggested above I would print url.absoluteString, response.statusCode and maybe some others to verify that the flow through the code is the expected one and to check that getList is actually called :). I don't see why you need to use DispatchQueue.main.async but that is probably not related to the issue.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine 
`
THIS Decode: Optional("{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":[\"758e0484-e3af-40cc-9a06-4242223e449a\",\"18197079-1303-4aa7-b96a-194e5b43d0b8\",\"8008800880088008\",\"c602752f-f550-48e6-aa6e-7728bd16226b\",\"a34e7158-26d4-4928-b29a-efd964e32a06\",\"012a19a4-68ee-4a2a-ae3a-3d972cfec374\",\"0461d864-6079-489d-94ef-8a756c9b41d5\"]}")
`


THIS LIST: ["758e0484-e3af-40cc-9a06-4242223e449a", "18197079-1303-4aa7-b96a-194e5b43d0b8", "8008800880088008", "c602752f-f550-48e6-aa6e-7728bd16226b", ", "0461d864-6079-489d-94ef-8a756c9b41d5"]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The code does everything correctly, I'm talking, I must have formed it badly, I don't know how to get each element from [String] in order to use it

**If it is important**:
**in order to make a request for them later**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to access the data elements of an array:

```
 // ....
 self.listId = decoded.data 

 for i in listId.indices {
     print("--> listId[\(i)] = \(listId[i]) ")
 }
 
 print("--> listId[0] = \(listId[0]) ")
 print("--> listId[1] = \(listId[1]) ")

 // ....
```

Read the **very basics of Swift**, specially regarding arrays here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you, I'm a fool
it really could be that simple